# undefined method `route' inside routes.rb error, Process exited with code: 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Iam following DIY tuitorial for building twitter clone. I have followed everything that he has done but i get the following error when I run the project just after doing bundle install for the twitter bootstrap gem.

```
Your code is running at https://uni-saga-ianlikono.c9users.io.

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `route' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x00000001ccc260> (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'


Process exited with code: 1
```

Comment: error is pretty clear, add your `routes.rb` file, probably on line 3 you have stray `route` written

Comment: What should i write?

Comment: route 'pages#index' thats my line 3

Comment: that should be `root` and not `route`, was it audio tutorial?

Comment: Thanks. Its now working

Comment: putting it as answer to sum it up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, line 3 in `routes.rb` contains the word `route` which is unexpected..

As discussed in comments, the line was

```
route 'pages#index'
```

This is not the correct syntax for defining `root` page, correct syntax is

```
root 'pages#index'
```

Refer *3.14 Using root* [`here`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)